# CA XCOM Data Transport - XCOMU0474E xcomd is already running. Multiple instances not supported

Tags: linux, certificate-authority

Does anybody know the problem described below?

It's a Red Hat Enterprise Linux running Computer Associates XCOM Data Transport.

```
 #/usr/sbin/xcomd
2009/05/18 08:46:48  PRG=xcomd PID=7618
    XCOMU0474E xcomd is already running. Multiple instances not supported.
 # ps aux | grep xcom
    root     10038  0.0  0.0 51084  716 pts/1    S+   08:53   0:00 grep xcom
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about the CA XCOM software that you refer here.

But if it behaves like most other services that run on linux, then probably this type of error can occur if the service was not previously not cleanly stopped. In such a case a previous 'pid' file that stores the process id still exists.

If the 'xcomd' has a stop or shutdown option then try that option first and then try starting it again.

Alternatively, you can try to manually try to move (or delete) the corresponding pid file out of the way. A rough guess for the name and location for this pid file would be /var/run/xcomd.pid. If the xcom.pid file has 7618 stored in it and you are sure that process no longer runs, then remove the pid file and try starting it up again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I think I am in the position to answer it correctly because I work as an engineer for CA XCOM Data Transport.

'xcomd' is the CA XCOM daemon process. The command is used to start and stop the daemon, as well as to set other parameters. Or in other words, xcomd command controls the daemon. The daemon itself runs as a background process to manage XCOM resources.

From the input you gave, it can be seen that you entered the command

```
#/usr/sbin/xcomd
```

at time 08:46:48 and

```
# ps aux | grep xcom
```

at time 08:53. So, there is a gap of around 7 minutes before you check if xcomd is already running or not. Now, depending upon how many users have access to the Red Hat Enterprise Linux machine mentioned by you, it is one of the possibilities that some other user might have stopped/killed xcomd meanwhile. And since **ps** produces a static list, that is, a snapshot of what is running when you execute the command, xcomd is not displayed in the output.

The error code **XCOMU0474E** simply means that xcomd is already running and you can't start more than one instance.

At this point if you want to stop the already running xcomd instance then you can do by using either the
**-c** or **-s** flag depending on whether a graceful or immediate cessation is desired.

**-c[y]**  - Kill the daemon process and free shared memory. This option should be reserved as a last resort since it will bring the scheduler down immediately.

**-s**      - Stop the XCOM daemon by sending a request to the scheduler.

Once you have stopped/killed the daemon successfully, restart it again and this time you will not get **XCOMU0474E** error.